# Passing variable into xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql-server, variables, xp-cmdshell

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server that checks for today's backup files (files that has a date in its filename). After checks, it will move on to `robocopy` these files to another folder.

The challenge: In this folder, there could be files from yesterday's or other dates. But only today's bak files are required for transfer.

```
--@day allows me to capture the day of a month
declare @day char(2)
set @day = RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2),DATEPART(DAY,GETDATE())),2)
--print @day

--In "MyFolder", it might containts files like 
--Project_backupfile_01_2006_02_28_001.bak
--OR Project_backupfile_01_2006_02_27_001.bak

--Currently I need to hard code 28 to represent 28th. How to pass in @day?
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'dir d:\myfolder\Project*28*.bak/b'

--Similarly, I would like to pass in @day variable so that the --Project_backupfile*02_*@day.bak

-- Copy the backup fules from ftp to a local drive
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'robocopy "d:\source" "E:\MSSQL\Restore\" Project_backupfile*_02_28*.bak /NFL /NDL /COPY:DAT /R:2 /W:1 /XO /E /Z /MT:10'
```

Answer (score 7):

Use a variable to form the command before passing it to `xp_cmdshell`

```
declare @cmd varchar(100)
select @cmd = 'dir d:\myfolder\Project*' + datename(day, getdate()) + '*.bak/b'
-- print @cmd
exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

Note: `datename(day, getdate())` will give you the day of the month as a string.

`stuff(convert(varchar(5), getdate(), 101), 3, 1, '_')` will give you `02_28`