# SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 137: Must declare the scalar variable "@result"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xp-cmdshell

When I run the following code to output an Sql query to a file, it works fine:

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT top 5 * from NK.[dbo].[eclubCustomerDelta]" queryout c:\nk\contacts.txt -c -T'
```

But I have saved my query in another variable earlier in the code:

```
SET @result = (SELECT @x,@y
FOR XML PATH('contacts'))
```

`@x` and `@y`are themselves variables defined earlier (the query gives the correct output when run reparately). This being said, a similar output of the query does not seem to be working:

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT @result" queryout c:\nk\contacts.txt -c -T'
```

Here is how my output looks:

> Starting copy...
>
> SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 137
>
> Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Must
>   declare the scalar variable "@result".
>
> SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
>
> Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Unable to resolve
>   column level collations
>
> BCP copy out failed

Comment: You are passing command line arguments to a command-line utility `bcp`, which is a separate exe. Why do you expect this separate exe would be able to see your `@result`?

Comment: try escaping  @ character

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing variable into xp\_cmdshell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35691620/passing-variable-into-xp-cmdshell)

Comment: @GSerg agree, but could you show me the way? in the code above my `@result` is an Xml variable. I don't think my question is a duplicate. The other question has another command and has nothing to do with Xml.

Comment: @Disasterkid It does not matter what your variable contains. The point is that you put the contents or the variable into the command string like you do with dynamic SQL.

Comment: @GSerg the query `SELECT @result` is exactly I need. If I put my entire query in the `bcp` command my code becomes very hard to read.

Comment: @Disasterkid Then also put `SET @result = ...` in your command, before the `select @result`, preceded by everything else that is referenced in the `set`. If you don't like that either, create a stored procedure/function with that code and call it by name from the command.

Comment: @GSerg my `@result` variable also contains references to other variables. Should I put the entire query in a bcp command? Isn't there a cleaner way of doing this?